# Find element with Enzyme in nested React component

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, enzyme

I am trying to write a for my component `TestComponent` that ensures the callback is fired when the user clicks on a button.  However, the button is not found (though I can see it in the HTML by calling `console.log(wrapper.html())`.

The button is inside another component that is used within `TestComponent`, if that matters.

Here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import TestComponent from './test-component.jsx';

describe('<TestComponent/>', () => {
  it('clicking "continue" button fires the callback', () => {
    const onClickContinue = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent />);
    console.log(wrapper.find('.btn-primary').length); // 0
    console.log(wrapper.html());                      // does have `.btn-primary`

    // wrapper.find('.btn-primary').simulate('click');
    // expect(onClickContinue.calledOnce).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out.  From https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html:

> Shallow rendering lets you render a component "one level deep" and assert facts about what its render method returns, without worrying about the behavior of child components, which are not instantiated or rendered.

This test needs to work with child components, so must use `mount` instead of `shallow`.  Here is the working code:

```
import React from 'react';
import expect from 'expect';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import TestComponent from './test-component.jsx';

describe('<TestComponent/>', () => {
  it('clicking "continue" button fires the callback', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<TestComponent />);
    const handleClickContinue = sinon.spy(wrapper.instance(), 'handleClickContinue');
    wrapper.find('.btn-primary').first().simulate('click');
    expect(handleClickContinue.calledOnce).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Also notice I changed from `onClickContinue` to `handleClickContinue`, as this method must exist in the component (not what its called in the `prop`).